# Re-bind helm-bibtex actions to number keys

Tags: key-bindings

The default behavior for `helm-bibtex` is to bind actions to the function keys `F1, F2,...`. How can I change this to use the number keys `1,2,...` instead?

Comment: Helm probably has a way to customize the keys. I'd check there.

Answer (score 1):

Find out what keymap they are bound in, in that context, and create your own keybindings for the number keys to the same commands, in that map.

If you want to also remove the function-key bindings, bind those keys to `nil` instead of a command, in that keymap.

If the keymap is not the `global-map` (which is likely) then use `define-key`.

But before you do anything, find out what the number keys already do in the mode you are interested in.  In most modes they are bound to a command such as `digit-argument`, which is used for a prefix argument (e.g., for use with `C-u`).  Typically you do *not* want to sacrifice that use.